# Permanently disable one activity component

Tags: applications, root-cloak

I have a [banking app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sbi.SBIFreedomPlus) which was detecting root despite being hidden by Magisk.

I managed to hide root from that app but on analyzing that app I found an activity that is very conveniently named `DETECT MAGISK` with activity name `com.sbi.rc.DetectMagisk`

I want to know if I can disable only that activity so that the app cannot even make an attempt to detect root (I am not sure if the app would work or not with that activity disabled, but worth a shot)

Pixel 4a, Android 12,rooted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command to disable app's components is `pm disable <package>/<component>`.

So, I ran this command:

```
~$ pm disable com.sbi.SBIFreedomPlus/com.sbi.rc.DetectMagisk
Component {com.sbi.SBIFreedomPlus/com.sbi.rc.DetectMagisk} new state: disabled
```

It was successful. But, the app refused to launch. In hindsight, this should have been obvious as the app is designed to work only *after* detecting device is not rooted and if the check itself is disabled, it logically shouldn't work.